# Monotonicity of function averages

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality, average

Please let me know if you know an answer to this problem. May be you could provide a reference to some publication on this topic?

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued  strictly convex function on $[0, 1]$. For any integer $k$ between $0$ and some positive integer $n$ let $x_k =k/n$. Consider the average value function $g(n)= \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(x_k)/(n+1) $. Is it true that $g(n)$ is decreasing?

Thank you!

Comment: Good question, and I believe the answer is yes after toying around with some numerical examples to build intuition.  I'm trying to find a proof.

Comment: Idea for an argument: look at the partitions as used to  approximate the Riemann integral from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Isn't this just weighted jensens?

Comment: I don't know about weighted Jensens, @CalvinLin, maybe you could elaborate in an answer?  One intuition here is that the sum is (up to an additive constant independent of $ n $) the result of the trapezoid rule for approximating the Riemann integral.  This intuition suggests an affirmative answer to the question, though I still can't pin down why the trapezoid rule should converge monotonically for a concave function.

Answer (score 3):

$g(n-1) \geq g(n) \Leftrightarrow (n+1) \sum f( \frac{i}{n-1}) \leq n \sum f( \frac{i}{n})$.

This follows by summing up the following inequlities:
$\begin{array} { l l l l l l l }
& & n \times f(0) & = & n \times f(0) &=& n \times f(0), \\      
1 \times f(\frac{0}{n-1}) &+& (n-1) \times f( \frac{1}{n-1} ) & \geq & n \times f( \frac{\frac{0}{n-1} + \frac{n-1}{n-1}}{n}) &=& n f(\frac{1}{n}), \\  
2 \times f( \frac{1}{n-1}) &+& (n-2) \times f( \frac{2}{n-1}) &\geq& n \times f ( \frac{\frac{ 2}{n-1} + \frac{2n-4}{n-1}}{n}) &=& n f(\frac{2}{n}), \\  
\vdots      \\
i \times f( \frac{i-1}{n-1}) & + & (n-i) \times f( \frac{i}{n-1}) & \geq & n \times f( \frac{\frac{ i^2 - i}{n-1} + \frac{ni - i^2}{n-1} } { n } ) & = & n f(\frac{i}{n}), \\
(n-1) \times f( \frac{n-2}{n-1} ) &+&  1 \times f( \frac{n-1}{n-1}) &\geq& n \times f(\frac{ \frac{ n^2-3n+2}{n-1} + \frac{n-1}{n-1} }{n}) &=& n f(\frac{n-1}{n}) \\   
n \times f(1) & & &=& n \times f(1)&=& n \times f(1) \\ 
\end{array}$

---

Note: Strict convexity gives strict inequalities, so the function is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Nice, essentially performing Jensen's inequality for each new point as a convex combination of the two nearest old points

Comment: Thank you, Calvin, for providing this elegant proof!

Answer (score 0):

The following related monotonicity facts are also true: If, in addition, $f(x)$ is decreasing, then the sequence $u(n)= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k)/n$ is decreasing and the sequence $v(n)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)/n$ is increasing.

For the affirmative answer to the original problem this additional assumption about  $f(x)$  is not needed.